# Search table using textbox and drop-down list to filter database (Real-Time Search)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a problem in filtering the database, I have this code but it doesn't show the filtered database after I clicked the submit button search.

```
<form method="POST" action="client.php">
<div id="Search"  style="display:none">
     <h4>Search Client</h4>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Keyword" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp &nbsp
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="search_by" name="search_by">
                    <option value="Reference">Reference</option>
                    <option value="Lastname">Lastname</option>
                    <option value="Firstname">Firstname</option>
                    <option value="Province">Province</option>
                    <option value="Request">Request</option>
                    <option value="Status">Status</option>
                    </select>
                </td> 
                 <td>
                    &nbsp &nbsp
                </td>  
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="btn_search" value="Search">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <?php
        $res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT*FROM client_info");
        echo "<table style='font-size:12px;border-spacing:5px; background-color:white; width:100%;'>";  
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th> Reference No </th>";
        echo "<th> Lastname </th>";
        echo "<th> Firstname </th>";
        echo "<th> Middlename </th>";
        echo "<th> Street </th>";
        echo "<th> Brgy </th>";
        echo "<th> Town </th>";
        echo "<th> Prov </th>";
        echo "<th> Mobile </th>";
        echo "<th> Email </th>";
        echo "<th> Event </th>";
        echo "<th> Venue </th>";
        echo "<th> No. of Attendants </th>";
        echo "<th> Request </th>";
        echo "<th> Payment Ammount </th>";
        echo "<th> Payment Status </th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>". $row["ref_no"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row["last_name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row["first_name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row["middle_name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["street"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["brgy"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["town"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["prov"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["mobile"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["email_add"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["event"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["venue"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["number_attendants"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["request_res"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["payment_amount"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["payment_res"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>"; 
        ?>
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['btn_search'])) {
        if ($_POST['search_by'] == 'Reference') {
           $res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT*FROM client_info WHERE ref_no LIKE '%".$_POST['text']."%'");
            echo "<table style='font-size:12px;border-spacing:5px; background-color:white; width:100%;'>";  
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th> Reference No </th>";
            echo "<th> Lastname </th>";
            echo "<th> Firstname </th>";
            echo "<th> Middlename </th>";
            echo "<th> Street </th>";
            echo "<th> Brgy </th>";
            echo "<th> Town </th>";
            echo "<th> Prov </th>";
            echo "<th> Mobile </th>";
            echo "<th> Email </th>";
            echo "<th> Event </th>";
            echo "<th> Venue </th>";
            echo "<th> No. of Attendants </th>";
            echo "<th> Request </th>";
            echo "<th> Payment Ammount </th>";
            echo "<th> Payment Status </th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>". $row["ref_no"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row["last_name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row["first_name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $row["middle_name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["street"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["brgy"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["town"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["prov"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["mobile"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["email_add"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["event"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["venue"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["number_attendants"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["request_res"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["payment_amount"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "<td><center>". $row["payment_res"] . "</center></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>"; 
        }  
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you repeat your sentence 3x?

Comment: triple X effect ? :p

Comment: Xander Cage is here!

Comment: @NathanRobb probably wouldn't let them post that much code without some more text to explain the problem.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I imagine there's a reason for that though lol

Comment: @NathanRobb Yeah, definitely. In this case, it looks like the problem is simple enough, though, even though there's more code than necessary.

Comment: @NathanRobb just added an answer. (At least it's what I _think_ the problem is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it *does* show the filtered results. It just looks like it doesn't because you're outputting the non-filtered results every time, then outputting the filtered results if the search form has been submitted. You just need to run a different query depending on whether or not the search form was submitted. Something like this.

```
// search form

if (isset($_POST['btn_search'])) {
    if ($_POST['search_by'] == 'Reference') {
       $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM client_info WHERE ref_no LIKE '%".$_POST['text']."%'");
    }
} else {
    $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM client_info");
}

// display your query results
```

Also, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. That's beside the point of the problem here, but you should look into using prepared statements instead of concatenating post values into your SQL.